# I can't get my GUI to load and recognize buttons using PySide

Tags: python, pyside, maya

Here is the error I am getting, which I am really confused about.  My UI file which I am loading has this button name and it matches.  But for some reason it doesn't seem to recognize and load it.  I just tried converting this code over to PySide (it was originally PyQt).  Am I doing something wrong in translating it?

## Error: AttributeError: file  line 25: 'swapRefGUI' object has no attribute 'swapRefBtn' #

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
import maya.cmds as cmds

class swapRefGUI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        uifile = QtCore.QFile('C:\Scripts\swapRef.ui')
        uifile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        ui = loader.load(uifile, parent)
        uifile.close()

        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

        self.swapRefBtn.clicked.connect(self.swapRefBtn_clicked)
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)               

    def swapRefBtn_clicked(self):
        pass                          

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    #app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    myGUI = swapRefGUI(None)
    myGUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are trying to access `swapRefBtn` through the class instance `swapRefGUI`, but you actually need to access it through the `ui` variable where you load. The 2nd argument of `loader.load` should also be `self` to display the qt gui in your window. There's also a few instances where you are trying to access objects from PySide like `QDialog`, when it should be `QtGui.QDialog` (because of the way you imported PySide module).

Here's some code that worked with a ui file.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
import maya.cmds as cmds

class swapRefGUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        uifile = QtCore.QFile('C:\Scripts\swapRef.ui')
        uifile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.ui = loader.load(uifile, self) # Qt objects are inside ui, so good idea to save the variable to the class, 2nd arg should refer to self
        uifile.close()

        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

        self.ui.swapRefBtn.clicked.connect(self.swapRefBtn_clicked) # Need to access button through self.ui
        #self.ui.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close) # This needs to have an existing function in the class or it will crash when executing

    def swapRefBtn_clicked(self):
        print 'WORKS'  

myGUI = swapRefGUI()
myGUI.show()
```