# PyQt6 with UI File

Tags: python, attributes, pyqt6

How can I solve the error:

> "AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute...".

I'm learning python and PyQt6. I would like to be capable to use the .ui file for my window app, however I can run the script but I cannot connect the objects such as button.

Here is the code:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui"
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()
        self.bottone.clicked.connect(self.cliccami) #here the problem, cannot find 'bottone' which is the button objectName in my UI file

    def cliccami(self):
        print("il bottone è stato cliccato")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

here is my UI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>674</width>
    <height>269</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="bottone">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>230</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>100</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>premimi</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="testo">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>230</x>
     <y>100</y>
     <width>121</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>cambiami</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

here the output

```
12:49:11: Starting /usr/bin/python3 -u widget.py...
qt.pysideplugin: Environment variable PYSIDE_DESIGNER_PLUGINS is not set, bailing out.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute and QSGRendererInterface::OpenGLRhi using QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi before constructing QGuiApplication.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/giulio/Projects/QtProjects/provaprova/widget.py", line 29, in <module>
    widget = Widget()
  File "/Users/giulio/Projects/QtProjects/provaprova/widget.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.load_ui()
  File "/Users/giulio/Projects/QtProjects/provaprova/widget.py", line 22, in load_ui
    self.bottone.clicked.connect(self.cliccami)
AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute 'bottone'
```

tried several commands, but cannot find the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't get my GUI to load and recognize buttons using PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176742/i-cant-get-my-gui-to-load-and-recognize-buttons-using-pyside)

Comment: Note that you tagged the question for PyQt, but you're actually using PySide. If you want and can use PyQt, then use the `loadUi()` function of the uic module, which works much better than the QUiLoader, since it actually "sets up" the ui on the current widget, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.